# Can I install a heat-recovery ventilator (HRV) in a garage?

Tags: hvac

I am building a high efficiency home in N. Minnesota, 2x6 construction, slab heat, spray foam insulation etc. Need to install an [heat-recovery ventilator (HRV)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heat_recovery_ventilation) unit, but only have space for it in the garage also with slab heat & foam insulation.  Local HVAC pro's tell me it can't be done, but cannot tell me why.  Any input would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

To get [Robert Nubel](https://diy.stackexchange.com/users/50610/robert-nubel)'s answer out of comment space so it can be voted on:

> Not sure about HRVs in particular, but in general your HVAC system can't be tied into your garage because of the potential for carbon monoxide from car exhaust to work its way back into your house.

Generally speaking, HVAC equipment cannot be in the garage due to the risk of sucking carbon monoxide (CO) gas from car exhaust into the house and poisoning the occupants. In order to put HVAC equipment into the garage, you must build a sealed, fire rated closet to install the HVAC equipment.

It can be done, but it's expensive and takes up floor space.

Comment: Yeah, your way is better, isherwood...

Comment: HVAC system *shouldn't* be tied into your garage. Any code that says you can't is local.

Answer (score 0):

It has to be 6' off the floor and hard-piped with 26 gauge steel.

<strike>Technically, yes, but you can't feed it back inside the house. The penetrations required would violate the firewall.</strike>

> IRC 309.1.1:  Ducts in the garage and ducts penetrating the walls and ceilings separating the dwelling from the garage shall be constructed of a minimum No. 26 gauge steel sheet or other approved material, and shall have no openings in the garage.

> Mechanical Code 304.6:  Appliances located in private garages and carports shall be installed with a minimum clearance of 6 feet above the floor.  Exception:  The requirements of this section shall not apply where the appliances are protected from motor vehicle impact in accordance with Section 304.3 (which addresses elevation of ignition source).

> https://www.energyvanguard.com/blog/want-bad-air-put-a-heating-cooling-system-in-your-attached-garage/

*"No. 26 gauge steel sheet"* - "it can't be done" - I'd pass on the job of hard piping an HVR too. We make money selling you stuff, not while putting it in, and if I can't use flexible then I'm out.

Comment: You could install a fire damper in the duct aligned with the firewall.

Comment: Firewalls can be penetrated, if done properly. That's not the primary concern with connecting the garage to the house.